# how to apply @if and @else condition in .scss file of angular component?

Tags: css, angular, sass

This is the code I want to apply in img tag of the component.

The **--invert-color** variable is coming from variable.scss file.
**Component.scss**

```
//Condition not working with variable
@if var(--invert-color)==1 {
  .card-content .card-icons{
    position: absolute;
    width: 35%;
    right: 10px;
    top: 40px;
    bottom:0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: var(--invert-color);
    filter:brightness(0) invert(1) ;// I want to change color from black to white
  }
}@else{
  .card-content .card-icons{
    position: absolute;
    width: 35%;
    right: 10px;
    top: 40px;
    bottom:0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: var(--invert-color);
    filter:brightness(0) invert(0) ;
  }

}
```

Even I cant use

```
 filter:brightness(0) invert(var(--invert-color)) ;
```

**Variable.scss** file

```
html[theme-mode="light-theme"]{
  --invert-color:0
};


html[theme-mode="dark-theme"]{
  --invert-color:1
};
```

Comment: you are facing this issue because the compiler expects an SCSS variable, but receives a different syntax

Comment: have a look:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if